# MySQL JOIN associative column with multiples row values in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, inner-join, associative

Table ORDEM

```
ord_id | name
1      -  'A'
2      -  'B'
3      -  'C'
4      -  'D'
```

Table ORCAMENTO

```
orc_id | type
  10   -  'AA'
  20   -  'BB'
  30   -  'CC'
  40   -  'DD'
```

Table ORDEM_ORCAMENTO

```
id | ord_id | orc_id  
1  -   1    -   10
2  -   1    -   20
3  -   2    -   30
4  -   2    -   40
```

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT o.*, oo.orc_id 
FROM ordem AS o
        INNER JOIN ordem_orcamento AS oo ON oo.ord_id = o.ord_id
ORDER BY o.ord_id ASC
```

Results Got:

```
1 - 'A' - 10
1 - 'A' - 20
2 - 'B' - 30
2 - 'B' - 40
```

Results Needed:

```
1 - 'A' - 10,20
2 - 'B' - 20,30
```

I want to put all id's from ORCAMENTO table that belongs to ORDEM table into an array...

I've tried many ways to figure it out but I haven't success...

Comment: Just return a result and process the array in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` allows you to select a group into a comma separated string

```
select o.ord_id, o.name, group_concat(oo.orc_id)
from ordem o
join ordem_orcamento oo on o.ord_id = oo.ord_id
group by o.ord_id, o.name
order by o.ord_id asc
```

Comment: It's Perfect, I was using GROUP_CONCAT without 'group by' and didn't work fine, But now all is working perfect... Tks

Answer (score 0):

You can build an array with php too, by looping the result

```
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $res) {
    $data[$res->ord_id][] = $res->orc_id
}

//output: foreach ($data as $orderitem) echo implode(",",$orderitem);
```

Comment: Could be, but I think about performance it wont work really well... Bringing clean results from the database still my best choice for performance...

Comment: yes of course. but if you need the seperate ids for some actions (counting etc), each time you have to explode the string.